# Examine CQ Dispatcher from client

Tags: adobe, iis-7.5, aem

I use special HTTP header X-Dispatcher-Info to debug the settings of AEM Dispatcher caching proxy plugin. This technique is described at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html#Debugging.

When one sends the X-Dispatcher-Info header, Dispatcher adds the X-Cache-Info header to its response.

The problem is after upgrading Dispatcher from 4.1.12 to 4.2.0 it no longer returns the X-Cache-Info header.

My Dispatcher works under IIS 7.5 in Windows 2008 Server R2 SP1 x64. And the backend server is AEM 5.6.1 SP2 on Tomcat 7.0.69.

Is this feature still available in CQ Dispatcher 4.2? If so, how can I make use of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info header is not produced by default with the version 4.2.0. You could enable the info header by adding the property `/info "1"` as a direct child of your `/farm` sections.